# etckeeper - access control

Tags: centos, git

I have etckeeper installed on ten servers with Centos 6 and Centos 7. It uploads / etc from the server to an individual git repository (it has its own for each server). My git is deployed based on Gitea. Since the etckeeper ssh key is installed in git (to access the repositories and download / etc there), from any server where etckeeper is installed, you can SSH access to all server repositories (this is viewing the repositories and its contents, performing various manipulations with repositories and so on). This compromises security, since the owner of any server with etckeeper installed can access the repositories of other servers that do not belong to him.

Question: how can I restrict access to repositories of "foreign" servers? It is necessary to restrict access both through the CLI and through the Gitea web interface

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has been cross-posted and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66470372/1256347